# WebDriverJs' getPageSource gives me an object rather than the page's source

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`res.json` is returning blank when I try display the source of the page. The Selenium log shows that the source code was retrieved. Any idea how I can receive the updated page source properly?

It returns the same thing if I use other functions like get current url.

Code:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub').withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).build();
     driver.get('http://www.google.com');
     var source = driver.getPageSource();
        console.log(source);
        res.json({ message: source });
```

`console.log` outputs:

```
 [{ then: [Function: then],                                                                                                                                                         
      cancel: [Function: cancel],                                                                                                                                                       
      isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

Selenium log:

```
16:17:30.273 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=firefox}]])                                                                                                 
16:17:30.286 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=firefox}]                                                                                                 
16:17:39.751 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=firefox}]]                                                                                                       
16:17:39.862 INFO - Executing: [get: http://www.google.com])                                                                                                                        
16:17:43.828 INFO - Done: [get: http://www.google.com]                                                                                                                              
16:17:43.863 INFO - Executing: [get page source])                                                                                                                                   
16:17:44.036 INFO - Done: [get page source]                                                                                                                                         
16:17:44.081 INFO - Executing: [delete session: d816aa4f-f5ad-4a59-aec0-4475cab4dff1])                                                                                              
16:17:44.206 INFO - Done: [delete session: d816aa4f-f5ad-4a59-aec0-4475cab4dff1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is a [*promise*](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Promises) to get the source, not the source itself. I'd expect you have to do something like:

```
source.then(function (src) {
    res.json({ message: src });
});
```

The clue there is that when you output `source` to the console, you get an object that has `then`, `cancel`, and `isPending` methods. The `then` method is very often used by promise frameworks to pass the callback that will be called when the promise is resolved.